# How to query the gitlab API from the browser?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Just to give some context, I'd like to implement a blog with gitlab pages, so I want to use snippets to store articles and comments. The issue is that querying the API from the browser triggers a CORS error. Here is the infamous code:

```js
const postJson = function(url, body) {
    const client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('POST', url);
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (client.readyState === 4) {
                client.status === 200
                    ? resolve(client.responseText)
                    : reject({status: client.status, message: client.statusText, response: client.responseText})
            }
        }
        client.send(body)
    })
};

postJson('https://gitlab.com/api/graphql', `query {
  project(fullPath: "Boiethios/test") {
    snippets {
      nodes {
        title
        blob {
          rawPath
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`).then(console.log, console.error);
```

That makes perfect sense, because it would allow to fraudulently use the user's session.

There are several options:

- Ideally, I would like to have an option to disable all form of authentication (particularly the session), so I could only access the information that is public for everybody.
- <strike>I could use a personal access token, but I'm not comfortable with this, because the scopes are not fine-grained at all, and leaking such a PAT would allow everybody to see everything in my account.</strike> (doesn't work)
- I could use OAuth2 to ask for every reader the authorization to access their gitlab account, but nobody wants to authenticate to read something.
- <strike>I could create a dummy account, and then create a PAT. That's the best IMO, but that adds some unnecessary complexity.</strike> (doesn't work)

What is to correct way to query the gitlab API from the browser?

Comment: Can you add more details? Is it a static site hosted by gitlab pages? Are you trying to do client side logic on a static site?

Comment: @ShashankV Yep, the page is hosted by gitlab pages, so the whole site is static & thus I cannot call the API at server side.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I have found this way to get the articles and the comments. The CORS policy was triggered because of the POST request with a JSON content. A mere GET request does not have this restriction.

I could recover the information in 2 times:

- I created a dummy account, so that I could have a token to query the API for my public information only,
- Then I used the API V4 instead of the GraphQL one:

  ```
  // Gets the snippets information:
  fetch('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/7835068/snippets?private_token=AmPeG6zykNxh1etM-hN3')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(console.log);

  // Gets the comments of a snippet:
  fetch('https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/7835068/snippets/1742788/discussions?private_token=AmPeG6zykNxh1etM-hN3')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(console.log);
  ```